# How can I retrieve the total number of orders in my Woocommerce store using the REST API?

Tags: rest, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there any way to retrieve the total number of orders on my Woocommerce store via REST API?

I am creating a list of orders on a separate site and I need my total order number (to paginate the list of orders). This is the endpoint I'm using:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?&consumer_key=ck_xxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxx
```

I've looked through the [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders) but there doesn't seem to be an option, does anyone know a way? It's only one integer!

Comment: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#retrieve-orders-totals

Comment: There it is! I was looking in the wrong place, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=100&_fields=id
```

In this way, by limiting the line to just the id, you will reduce the response time and learn the numbers. It's a bit of an evasive answer, but I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

/wp-json/wc/v3/reports/orders/totals

I found the real solution, try sending a request to this address.